# Muting a Mic Using AudioDeviceController

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

Hello Eveyone I am trying to mute/unmute a default mic using AudioDeviceController but it looks like I cannot initialize the variable.

I have since used AudioDeviceModulesManager because you can get an object by device ID.

How do I initilize the Variabale like I do with AudioDeviceModulesManager .

```
    public App()
    {
        var endpointID = MediaDevice.GetDefaultAudioCaptureId(AudioDeviceRole.Default);
        AudioDeviceModulesManager MyController = new AudioDeviceModulesManager(endpointID);
        var thing = MyController.FindAll();
        var test = thing[0];

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your interesting, derive from official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.devices.audiodevicecontroller?view=winrt-18362) remake part, *To get an instance of this object, retrieve the [MediaCapture.AudioDeviceController](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.mediacapture.audiodevicecontroller?view=winrt-18362#Windows_Media_Capture_MediaCapture_AudioDeviceController) property.*
So we can only get `AudioDeviceController` instance from `MediaCapture` class. For more detail please check this [**Basic photo, video, and audio capture with MediaCapture**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/basic-photo-video-and-audio-capture-with-mediacapture#capture-audio) tutorial.